# Is a cosmetic logotype on an outer copper layer a bad idea?

Tags: pcb, copper, etching

I've seen many people add logotypes and other graphics in the copper layers of PCBs, often also removing the solder mask in these places to expose the bare (or rather plated) copper.

Is there anything electrically, mechanically or chemically that makes this a bad idea?

Comment: Floating copper can cause EMI issues

Comment: Depending on how it is encoded this can be a huge amount of data in the Gerber's.  Silkscreen or decorative soldermask are more common art choices

Comment: @DKNguyen Can you elaborate? How is this different form any other conductive object near the PCB such as screws in a device case?

Comment: @ChrisStratton But that would be the same regardless of the layer, no? Logo being on the copper layer doesn't mean more data than on the silk screen layer.

Comment: @EmilEriksson I think it has to do with proximity. I'm a bit fuzzy on the details but I think it has something to do with re-radiation of noise

Comment: @EmilEriksson A metal screw isn't always great either! https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149993/how-to-mount-toroidal-transformer-in-metal-chassis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there really aren't much downsides, especially with solder mask openings.

The solder mask is electrically quite insignificant. If you'd have the opening on an impedance controlled trace it would have slight effect, but you wouldn't have it there anyway, because it would be ugly. If you have ENIG finish on the board, there's added cost, because there will be gold on the logo as well. You can avoid the cost by placing the logo on a place where there's no copper under the solder mask, but then it isn't as nice and flashy.

You can't make fancy or small graphics with solder mask, because thin lines don't stick to the board well.

Etching the logo to copper might have some effect on EMC, depending what's underneath. If there's a ground plane on the next layer, then you most likely don't have any issues. The modern etching processes are quite impressive so with copper you can get a bit more details than with solder mask, but it might come with added cost, if the board doesn't otherwise have thin traces on that layer. And there's also the added cost of added gold with ENIG finish.

Comment: This is a four layer board with dedicated ground and power so there is no copper in this spot since there is no pour. Thus, the logo means adding dead copper in a previously empty spot as well as opening the solder mask there.

Comment: So there is a GND or power plane under the logo. Then I wouldn't be worried. And if the EMC problems do arise, it is easy to peel off the logo to see if it is causing them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer here is common sense.

If the logo is placed on some previously empty space and its presence does not require any component placement or routing change there is no harm in doing it. If you're already using ENIG, by all means open the solder mask and make the logo shinny. I doubt that the PCB fab house will charge you more for the extra gold used. If there is no plating restrain from the idea of leaving exposed copper - that's never a good thing.

If the logo disrupts a ground that is critical for shielding or for controlled impedance traces, or if the logo presence risks creating an undesired coupling path, resist the temptation to do it. Functionality is way more important!

Comment: In this case, it's a four layer board with dedicated ground and power plane so the logo will be added copper in what was an empty space in addition to opening the solder mask there.

Comment: It sounds like you should be good then.

Answer (score 0):

We do this in our designs so that we can save money by totally avoiding silkscreen printing. The text as such will be small, isolated from all other sections in the circuitry and doesn't create any trouble with EMI EMC. Ofcourse this wouldn't be placed some where close to a impedance matched tracks but rather in a place which is easy to read but without harming any other sensitive sections.